# How to fix settimeout memory leak problem in javascript

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, settimeout

I have a JS function like this

```
function check() {
    ...do something
}
```

Now, I want to run it when script start, and at start of everyday (00:00:01 everyday). My code now look like this

```
function check() {
    ...do something

    let today = new Date();
    let tomorrow = new Date();
        tomorrow.setHours(0,0,1,0);
        tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate()+1);

    console.log("next check in", tomorrow-today);
    setTimeout(() => { check() }, tomorrow-today);
}
check();
```

I'm using setTimeout inside check(). I think it's bad code because it will create a loop, and function check() will never been cleanup. How to fix it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "`check()` will never be cleaned up"?  What do you feel is occupying memory?  Have you done any analysis to prove there's a memory leak here?

Comment: Actually I didn't run an analysis to prove there's a memory leak. I think the check function need to wait for setTimeout to finish, after that, it can be destroyed. But the setTimeout call another check() function that will wait forever ( call another check and so on ). So, every check() function that loaded to memory will never be destroyed. Am I right ?

Comment: It sounds like the problem you feel is possible here is a stack overflow.  See the answer for an explanation why a `setTimeout()` loop won't cause stack overflows.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that uncontrolled recursion could cause exhaustion of resources due to the stack growing indefinitely.  For example, the following Javascript program will crash after `check()` is executed sufficient times without first `return`ing:

```
function check() {
  check();
}
check();
```

The following code will not crash in this way:

```
function check() {
  setTimeout(check, 1000);
}
check();
```

This code can run indefinitely without exhausting the stack because each time `check()` is run, it is allowed to run to completion and `return` before it is run in the future.

This works because the `setTimeout()` function doesn't directly run `check()`.  Instead, it tells the Javascript runtime to schedule an execution of `check()` for 1s into the future.  When it and `check()` have completed, the Javascript stack becomes empty.  1s later, the execution of `check()` is *queued and eventually executed* as long as the Javascript stack is clear.

Since the Javascript stack must be clear before `check()` can run, stack overflows are avoided.

Comment: Is there any different between `setTimeout(check, 1000);` vs `setTimeout(() => { check() }, 1000);` . Does the second one will cause stack overflows

Comment: Is there any difference between ... what ... ? :)

Comment: I write this function in a class, so the setTimeout will like this : `setTimeout(this.check.bind(this), 1000);` or `setTimeout(() => { this.check() }, 1000);` , does it matter ? Still no memory leak ?

Comment: `setTimeout()` runs the provided callback as a function and provides no arguments, normally you can just pass the function directly to `setTimeout()`.  If the function you're passing to `setTimeout()` is actually a method of an object, you need to bind the object to the function.  So, in this case, either of the two ways you provided will result in `this` being correctly bound to the object while `this.check()` is executing.  And there won't be any stack overflows*

* - because `check()` needs to be able to access any variables it closes on, any objects `check()` uses will remain in memory.

Comment: ^ but that wouldn't be a memory leak, unless whatever `check()` is accessing is growing in size, or `check()` doesn't really need to be accessing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192878/discussion-between-ctt-and-boygiandi).

Answer (score 0):

You could add the function clearTimeout(timer):

```
let timer = setTimeout(() => check());

clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: It's not correct. I want to run function at 00:00:01 everyday ( script run forever ). That's why I need the delay setTimeout(check, `tomorrow-today`)